# Including and excluding qt modules and addons while configuring Qt5.5.1

Tags: c++, qt, ubuntu, beagleboneblack

Can someone explain what is a correct way to include some modules and addons while doing ./configure in Qt5.5.1?

I should have a x11 addon installed and tried that with:

> ./configure -qt-x11
>
> ./configure -qt-x11extrass

but it doesn't work.

I am reading [this](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/configure-options.html) for configure options, but I figured out that many things you have to guess how they need to be done. I am building qt5.5.1 on Ubuntu 14.04.3 to cross-compile for BBB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to build some module (all module dependency packages must be installed first), you need to go to module directory (for example qtmultimedia in qt directory) and run qmake (built for your specific architecture), after that make and sudo make install. Now you will be able to include required module into your .pro file.